# How to fix text alignment with logo in HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make sure all the padding aligns as well as the text and logo aligning in this html.

The code I've used to make everything align is listed below.

```html
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 580px;table-layout: auto;" width="580">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="left" valign="top" style="font-family:'Arial, 'Georgia', Times New Roman, serif;font-weight:normal;font-size:15px;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;line-height:19px; color:#000000;" class="" width="400">
        <div class="ee_editable" style="position: static;">
          <div class="" style="padding-top: 10px;"><br></div>
          <div class="headline">DISCOVER OUR<br> LATEST OFFERS</div>
          <div> </div>
      </td>
      <td width="180">
        <a href="https://dmtrk.net/t/20AS-67H0B-UDWVGK-3JC7VW-1/c.aspx" target="_blank">
          <img src="http://www.kindlewood.co.uk/bmw_images/minilogo180x80.png" alt="MINI" width="117" height="52" class="ee_editable ee_smallimage ee_pnggif_image" title="MINI" align="right" border="0">
        </a>
      </td>

    </tr>


    <tr>
      <td class="ee_dropzone" width="580" align="left" style="width: 580px;">
        <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="ee_element ee_imageelement" ee-type="element" data-title="Image" style="width: 580px;table-layout: auto;">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td style="font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px;" class=""><img border="0" src="https://i.emlfiles4.com/cmpimg/0/0/7/3/9/files/10607126_day10mniheader.png" style="width: 100%; min-height: auto; display: block; max-width: 100%;" class="ee_editable" width="580"></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

The above code is wrapped in a  code like this:

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="640" style="width: 640px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);table-layout: auto;" class="w320" bgcolor="#ffffff">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td align="center" style="min-width: 320px; padding-top: 0;padding-right: 0;padding-bottom: 0;padding-left: 0;" width="640">
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width: 580px;table-layout: auto;" width="580">
```

Right now, the page displays as so:

[image]

But I need the white mini pic, text and logo to align with the rest of the page. Thanks for any input!

Comment: Could you create a dummy jsfiddle or similar to demonstrate the incorrect behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to span the td with the image across two columns, since the row above as two td's, if that makes sense.

So if you change

```
<td class="ee_dropzone" width="580" align="left" style="width: 580px;">
```

to

```
<td colspan="2" class="ee_dropzone" width="580" align="left" style="width: 580px;">
```

you should be good to go.